# Is there a way to find out the number of hits/lookups on a particular Oralce table?

Tags: oracle11g

Is there a way to find out the number of hits/lookups on a particular Oracle table?(i.e, how often is a table queried per amount of time) without going for auditing(FGA)?

I'm able to get some information from the `gv$SQL`, `gv$SQL_AREA` and `dba_tab_modifications` but it's not up to the mark.

Answer (score 1):

If you are licensed to use the AWR, [`dba_hist_seg_stat`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10755/statviews_2143.htm) has information about the I/O (logical and physical) done on each segment during each snapshot.  If you aren't licensed to use the AWR, you can query the [`v$segstat`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10755/dynviews_2061.htm) and [`v$statname`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10755/dynviews_2117.htm) tables (joining on `statistic#`).  There are a ton of statistics that you can get information about most of which you couldn't care less about.  Something like "consistent gets" would be a reasonable thing to look at but you can get a ton of detail depending on how you want to slice and dice the data.  The downside, though, is that the data isn't historical-- you'd need to do thing like save off the current values on a regular basis if you want to track activity over time.

Comment: Thank you. But I'm looking for the number of queries accessing a particular table in one hour/day duration without going for auditing.

Comment: @KumarEk - If you really want to count "queries" (which seems like an odd metric-- do you really want to count 1000 single-row queries differently from 1 query that reads 1000 rows) it would seem like `v$sql` sampled at a high enough frequency would give you the information you're interested in (assuming you can parse the object names out of the query or out of the query plan).  You said that `v$sql` was "not up to the mark" though so I don't know what information you're missing or what stumbling block(s) you've hit.